# Unit testing captcha in yii

Tags: unit-testing, yii, phpunit, captcha

How to unit test a form with captcha?

I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function createAction() on a non-object in framework/validators/CCaptchaValidator.php on line 65

How can I fix this error?

I have tried the code below:

```
$c = Yii::app()->createController('module/action');
Yii::app()->controller = $c[0];
$captcha = new CCaptchaAction(Yii::app()->controller, 'captcha');
$model->captcha = $captcha->getVerifyCode();
```

but I get the error below:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getUniqueId() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\web\widgets\captcha\CCaptchaAction.php on line 221

any ideas?

Comment: Before writing unit tests it makes sense to learn language basics. Unit testing **is** a rocket science. If you cannot understand what that fatal means - spend some time learning php before you continue.

Comment: thanks for your really helpful comment! i know what that fatal means, but i don't know how should i fix it. if you don't know too please let others answer and help me!

Comment: the answer won't help you - since you started doing really complicated things before learning basics. "i know what that fatal means" -- so take and fix it. You either know it and fix it, or don't know it and read some book for newbies.

Comment: if you don't want help please let others do it.if i had time i didn't ask question here. best regards.

Answer (score -1):

i fix this error by ignoring captcha rule and give it a custom value and it works!

i remove this part of  rules in my form:

```
array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements())
```